# Mediafile wp8 does not play using Uri

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

On my Windows Phone 8 project, I have defined MediaElement on my Dashboard.xaml as below,

```XAML
<MediaElement x:Name="MusicMediaElement" Height="100" Width="100"                            
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="176,100,204,69"                            
                Volume="1"
                Source="{Binding CurrentCountdownItem.MusicFile}"
                MediaFailed="beep_MediaFailed" 
                MediaOpened="beep_MediaOpened"
                AutoPlay="False"/>
```

When user selects the music File on NewItem.xaml page, i set the value as follows,

```C#
Uri MusicItem = new Uri("../Assets/Music/Sleep_Away.wma", UriKind.Relative);
MyNewItem.MusicFile = MusicItem.ToString();
```

MyNewItem value is copied to CurrentCountdownItem properly using viewModel.

On Dashboard, `OnNavigatedTo()` method, i have this code,

```C#
MusicMediaElement.Source = new Uri(CurrentCountdownItem.MusicFile, UriKind.Relative);
MusicMediaElement.Play();
```

But the music does not play, and i get error code 3100 instead, invoked from `beep_MediaOpened()` method which gets invoked if it can not open the file.

I have marked the music file as Content and other Image files inside `Asset/Image` folder are wrking fine as per this logic. I searched a lot for 3100 error and to access Music files using Uri, but did not get any working result. Any help on Binding `MediaElement` Source property from Uri is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your MusicItem Uri to following.

```C#
Uri MusicItem = new Uri("/Assets/Music/Sleep_Away.wma", UriKind.Relative);
```

**EDIT**

You are playing your audio in the `OnNavigatedTo()` event. If you set a breakpoint in `OnNavigatedTo` and `beep_MediaOpened` event handlers, you can see that `beep_MediaOpened` event fires after `MusicMediaElement.Play()` line has finished executing. So the problem is obvious. Your mp3 file is not opened when you try to play the file.

So you can set the Source of the `MusicMediaElement` in the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler and then play the mp3 in the `beep_MediaOpened` event handler like bellow. This will play the file after the file is properly opened by the media element.

```C#
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    MusicMediaElement.Source = new Uri(CurrentCountdownItem.MusicFile, UriKind.Relative);
}

private void beep_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MusicMediaElement.Play();
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Hey, this solved the 3100 error, but the song still does not play.

Comment: Does MediaOpened event fire? Set a breakpoint and please chack

Comment: Yes, MediaOpened event gets triggered, and also MediaFailed does not get triggered.

Comment: Also, the music playes fine(!!!) as soon as the app launches(and lands on Dashboard.xaml) when set AutoPlay="True". But i want to be able to control it and play it only when user sets the music flag on - which i am trying using MusicMediaElement.Play()...

Comment: Yes, it worked! I never would have guessed that the beep_MediaOpened() gets called when you set the Source property and not when you set call Play() method. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You are welcome :) its always good to check to see if media is opened before you play coz, it might take some time especially if the media file is large.